# How can I use an alias for column name in linq method-based query?

Tags: c#, linq

I have two tables:

**Table1** that has columns:

- Id (Int, PK)
- CountryId (int, FK to Table2)

And some others

**Table2** that have columns:

- Id (Int, PK)
- Name (navchar)

And some others

I need to make a request with a linq method-based query similar to this sql-query:

```
SELECT 
    *,
    [Table2].[Name] AS [Country]

FROM  [dbo].[Table1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Table2]
ON [Table1].[CountryId] = [Table2].[Id]
```

I tried this one:

```
db.Table1.Join(db.Table2, s => s.CountryId, c => Id, (s, c) => new {s, Country = c.Name });
```

It works but in the result table I have a column with countries’ names labeled as “Name”, but not “Country”.

How can i use an alias for column name in linq method-based query in this case?

Comment: You're asking the wrong question.  It really does not matter what the SQL table names are called, what you want is the resulting objects that are projected have a specific name.  This has nothing whatsoever to do with the SQL Alias.

Answer (score 0):

try below

```
  var results = from tbl1 in db.Table1
                join tbl2 in db.Table2 on tbl1.CountryId = tbl2.Id
                select new {
                            Id = tbl2.Id,
                            ..  // other columns from Table1
                            ..  // other columns from Table1
                            Country = tbl2.Name
                            };
```

Comment: It works fine. But cat i do the same thing with **Method** Syntax? [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/query-syntax-and-method-syntax-in-linq)

Comment: yes, I think you may need to do .select( new {}) after join() not inside the join.

Comment: This is basically the query in the question rewritten in *comprehensive syntax* (disregarding the inessential variable names, only `new {s` is replaced by `new { s.Id`). I don't see how it answers the question that is based on a wrong assumption (see the comment).